# System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation reporting x86 instead of x64

Tags: c#, .net-core, processor

I was just getting into a project that loads a `.dll` based on processor architecture.  Compile runs fine but at runtime I receive a `System.BadImageFormatException`.

On further inspection I noticed the code was referencing the package `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` v4.3.0 and checking for ProcessArchitecture and was reporting X86 instead of X64.

I'm running Windows 10 on a 64bit i7 processor and ran the following in a test project:

```
// returns true
var is64Bit = IntPtr.Size == 8;

// returns true
// kernel32 pinvoke attempted, shortened here just to get the point across
GetNativeSystemInfo(ref info);
var isReally64Bit = info.wProcessorArchitecture == 9;

// returns true
// kernel32 shortened
GetSystemInfo(ref info);
var isReallyReally64Bit = info.wProcessorArchitecture == 9;

// returns false (ProcessorArchitecture = x86)
var isProcessor64 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessorArchitecture == 
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Architecture.X64;
```

The first three approaches identifies I'm on x64 Architecture, the last tells me I'm x86. Is there something I'm missing?  I'm targeting .netcore 2.0 and reviewed the source [RuntimeInformation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/RuntimeInformation/RuntimeInformation.Windows.cs) and [SYSTEM_INFO](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c55435befeb372707558a5c441b3c64bf243948f/src/Common/src/Interop/Windows/kernel32/Interop.SYSTEM_INFO.cs) but nothing looks out of the ordinary.

** **UPDATE** **

I am targeting .netcore 2.0 and notice from the RuntimeInformation source that it is calling GetSystemInfo and in my test I'm calling GetNativeSystemInfo.  I have tried calling both and compiled x64 explicitly and in my test code above both give me x64.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`System.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.osarchitecture?view=netcore-2.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_RuntimeInformation_OSArchitecture) instead.

Or, if using .NET Framework < 4.7.1, there is a [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem?view=netcore-2.0#System_Environment_Is64BitOperatingSystem) boolean property that you can use to determine the OS bitness.

Comment: I'm running in hopes to be cross platform so .NET Framework is out unfortunately (I'll update my question).  OSArchitecture also reports Architecture.x86.  Maybe my i7 is a Pentium 4? :-)